# "z-index" in php GD

Tags: php, z-index, gd

In css, we have a property called "**z-index**", what is the same in PHP GD and Image Functions to control the "**z-index**"?

I've been searching but I can't find one, please help.
Thankyou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there nothing existing like z-index in php GD library
but there several ways to overlap image over image or text over image

```
$redimg = imagecreatetruecolor(100, 100);
$image = imagecreatefrompng('image.png');

// sets background to red
$red = imagecolorallocate($redimg, 255, 0, 0);
imagefill($redimg, 0, 0, $red);

// Merge the red image onto the PNG image
imagecopymerge($image, $redimg, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 100, 75);

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
imagedestroy($image);
imagedestroy($redimg);
```

here one example, or let me know, what exactly you trying to do, I will help you
There's more information [here](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php).